# Math operation with databinding data for XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to do math with data binding in my android studio java project. I'm printing $15.00 in a TextView with the code `android:text="@{tvPlan.price}"`. I need to multiply the data here by 2, so I have to print $30.00. Is it possible to do this with xml?

Comment: why do you want to do it in xml? Why don't you do it in the `onCreate` method?

Answer (score 0):

android Text View text attribute does not accept Float value, for that you should write a custom Binding Adapter like below:

```
 @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    public static void setText(TextView view, Float value) {
        view.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }
```

and in your XML :

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@{(float)2*temp}"/>
```